# how to get a single row based on my condition

Tags: postgresql, relational-division

I have following rows in my user table as

[image]

Now I want to get user having all accesstype as view,edit and share. So I need to get two rows out of this as

[image]

How can I achieve this using postgresql statement.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What if a user had more types than just those three? Or to put it in another way: do you want those users who have **exactly** those three access types, or **at least** those three access types?

Comment: yes i want those users who have exactly those three access types

Comment: Unrelated but: this is a rather questionable design. Why is the user name and age repeated in each row? I would have expected the `id` column to be a foreign key that points to a "users" table that stores the name and other user attributes - but age is not an attribute that should be stored in a "users" table as that value essentially changes every day.

Comment: exactly we should not have these repeated id,name and age in a table but i put a scenario where i get these rows as a result of my sub query and again i want to get the data as i described.

Comment: hi @a_horse_with_no_name can you suggest me the query if i need at least those three access types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the rows that have **exactly** those three access types, you can aggregate them into an array:

```
select id, name, age
from the_table
group by id, name, age
having array_agg(accesstype order by accesstype) = array['edit', 'share', 'view']
```

Note that the order of the elements in the `array[...]` expression matters for the `=` operator used because `array['a', 'b']` is not equal to `array['b', 'a']`.

Alternatively you can use `bool_and()`

```
select id, name, age
from the_table
group by id, name, age
having bool_and(accesstype in ('edit', 'share', 'view'))
   and count(distinct accesstype) = 3
```

Comment: ya i tried solution 1 and its working fine for me. Thank you so much...... i will try second solution as well.

Comment: Hi @a-horse-with-no-name If i need the rows which have minimum edit,share and view access. Not exactly edit,view and share access, then how should i use this query? can you suggest the changes i need to do in above query?

Comment: okay so I tried this way now :  select id, name, age
from the_table
group by id, name, age
having bool_or(accesstype in ('edit', 'share', 'view'))
   and count(distinct accesstype) >= 3     and its working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT id, name, age
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, age
         , count(distinct accesstype) over (partition by id) as cnt
    FROM T
    WHERE accesstype IN ('view','edit','share')
) AS U
WHERE cnt = 3
```

Assuming id, accesstype is unique you can change that to:

```
SELECT id, name, age
FROM (
    SELECT distinct id, name, age
         , count(accesstype) over (partition by id) as cnt
    FROM T
    WHERE accesstype IN ('view','edit','share')
) AS U
WHERE cnt = 3
```

Untested since you did not provide a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or similar. For future posts please include something that makes it easy to reproduce your scenario.

You may also consider normalizing your tables into a separate relation for access type. Also, age is something you should derive from for example birth date. As of now, you will have to update this attribute on a regular basis (not clear on how you know when raj becomes 17 years old)

Comment: if I try solution 1 I get error as ERROR:  DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions but if I try solution 2 i get all row not the distinct rows

Comment: @RajeshKumar no, you would not get all rows. You did not run the query exactly as suggested.

Comment: @Lennart Okay will try again